# Linq2nHibernate in business layer?

Tags: linq-to-nhibernate

I would like to know, wheter it is a good idea and doesn't breaks n-tiered pattern, if I make the DAL return IQueryable - Collections and then use Linq in the BLL to do my queries?
What is about n-tiered then? Does that mean, that all my entities are fetched from databased an then queried in memory?... that would be awesome...

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your UnitOfWork implementation. Use Nhibernate LINQ, and make sure the Session is not closed every time you do a LINQ operation on the IQueryable that is returned from your DAL.